# How can I create OSGI plugin jars without using Eclipse?

Tags: plugins, ant, jar

I am able to create and export jar files for my OSGI plugin bundles using Eclipse. Is there any way in which I can do the same activity but without using Eclipse?

I have tried following:

While exporting jars in Eclipse there is option of 'save as ant script'. I saved this file and ran it using ran ant -buildfile antscript.xml. But it doesn't work.

I have jdk and ant tool, so I was thinking whether it is possible to do it without bringing Eclipse in picture.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, an eclipse plugin is just the compiled classes of the plugin and the proper manifest. Then a classic call of the `javac` and `jar` tasks can do the job. Obviously here you would loose every OSGi specific check at compile time.